# Can't get the real size of the image in HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image of a ball that I get from outer resource and I need to get the size of the image (height and width) for further calculations, but what I tried it shows 0 (but it's 40px actually)

Here is the whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ball to center</title>
    <style>
      #field {
        width: 200px;
        border: 10px groove black;
        background-color: #00FF00;
        position: relative;
      }

      #ball {
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="field">
      <img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let field = document.getElementById('field');
      let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
      console.log(`natural height and width: ${ball.naturalHeight} - ${ball.naturalWidth}`);
      console.log(`client height and width: ${ball.clientHeight} - ${ball.clientWidth}`);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you try to get the dimensions of the image before it loads, I imagine that they would be zero.  Try doing your logic after the load event happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only check the size of the image after it loads. You could use the `loaded` property of the image element to see if it's already loaded, otherwise attach a handler to the load event.,

```
let ball = document.getElementById('ball');

const checkImgSize = el => {
    console.log(`natural height and width: ${el.naturalHeight} - ${el.naturalWidth}`);
    console.log(`client height and width: ${el.clientHeight} - ${el.clientWidth}`);
};

if( ball.loaded )
    checkImgSize(ball);
else 
    ball.addEventListener('load', function(){ checkImgSize(this) }, { once: true });
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. Instead, if you have something new to add, add an answer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach, is that the code is executed before the page is loaded. As seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807895/4754538), you can do something like this with vanilla javascript to wait until page is loaded.

```js
let field = document.getElementById('field');
let ball = document.getElementById('ball');

window.onload = () => {
  console.log(`natural height and width: ${ball.naturalHeight} - ${ball.naturalWidth}`);
  console.log(`client height and width: ${ball.clientHeight} - ${ball.clientWidth}`);  
};
```